# ShareKit for Facebook in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, facebook, sharekit

I can't get ShareKit to work.  I dragged ShareKit into my app with checked copy option.  I also updated the shkconfig file with my Facebook key, secure key, and used the following code:

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:@"Praveen Kumar Tripathi"];
SHKFacebook *faceBook=[SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
[faceBook share];
```

in viewDidLoad.

But I'm not able to see Facebook screen. I'm seeing a blank screen.

Answer (score 2):

You weren't completely clear, so I'm not sure what your asking, but it sounds like you want to show a facebook login at launch.  The way you do that is like this:

First, `#import "SHKFacebook.h"`
then in your button, put then in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
SHKItem *item;
```

this creates the sharekit item

then:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/...?mt=8"];
```

put the link to your app here.  This link is so if someone clicks on the Facebook post, they will be directed to the iTunes store to download your app.

Then set the basic text for your post.  This text is set by you.  The user **Cannot** change this text.  (Obviously this is what I do, you can make this text anything you want)

```
item = [SHKItem URL:url title:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I'm playing someGame on my iPhone! My Highscore is %i, think you can beat it?", highScoreInt]];
```

Then set up the post like this:

```
item = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"Share Me!"];
```

finally show the item:

```
[SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: what if the app hasn't been published yet. any thoughts on how to put the link to the app in that case? thanks.

Comment: Well, do you have a developers account with apple?  IF so, you could like to your account on the store.  Basically it links to all the apps you have available.  Then just in your next update change the link

Comment: thanks. that's actually what i just did. a link to the dev. account and i'll do as you recommend and update once the app has been approved.

Comment: Since this answer helped you, would you mind checking the green arrow next to my answer

Comment: sorry about that. the arrow option that's usually there is missing though.